# Way to convert absolute references to relative/indirect ones?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a method or Macro anyone knows about that can change a formula into an indirect one?

For example, all the formulas on my sheet currently are written as:

`=SUM(Sheet2!A1:A10),` is there a way to quickly change this to an `INDIRECT` function like:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!"&"A1"):Sheet2!$A$10)`

This isn't hard changing it for one formula, but for 100s of formulas, each containing 3-4 references to other sheets, it would take a very long time correcting this.

The issue is arising from the fact that I am summing a range, however each time I insert a new row at the top, the formula doesn't refer to the correct cells. Trying to figure out a way to write a better formula, so I don't have to manually changing the row number each time.

Comment: Find and Replace is the only built-in feature for this.  You could write a macro, but it would be pretty specific to your requirements.  The site isn't intended as a free "write me code" service.  However, people here will help you with specific issues you encounter trying to write it yourself if you post your work and describe the problem you're having.

Comment: Alternatively instead of using indirect which I believe is a volatile function you could use `=sum(INDEX(A:A,1):A10)`  When you insert a new row, A10 becomes A11 but Index(A:A,1) will still return A1.  And the nice thing there is index is not a volatile function.  You would need to manually enter it though or potentially do a search and replace as fixer suggested.  Rember to set it to look inside formulas.

Comment: If all you are looking  to replace common Formula with common one, then simplest is Find & Replace but the fastest is Macro!!

Comment: I use free [regular expression add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) in Excel, that can help you with replace.

Answer (score 0):

*This Macro will help you to Find and Replace Formula in the Sheet.*

```
Sub FindReplaceFormula()

Cells.Replace What:="=SUM(Sheet2!A1:A10)", Replacement:= _
        "=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!"&"A1"):Sheet2!$A$10)", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

*You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*